# Why does the Dialog align to the bottom instead of the center by default in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-jetpack-compose

I have an issue with the default alignment of a **`Dialog`** in Jetpack Compose. The dialog consistently appears at the bottom of the screen. Interesting part is that it works well on Pixel3, 4 (Android 14) and Oppo but it doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy (Android 13). I mean dialog is aligned on bottom of the screen. I tried to make a Box with fillMaxSize() and handle click events out of dialog but it doesn't work as expected. Do what can I try to solve this issue?

[image: dialog-bug]

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            YourAppTheme {
                Dialog(onDismissRequest = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .background(Color.White)
                            .padding(16.dp),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Title",
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleSmall,
                            color = Color.Black
                        )
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
                        Text(
                            text = "Desc",
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
                            color = Color.Black
                        )

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wrap it with Surface

Comment: Im having the same problem. One clue is that when you remove the application of android:theme="@style/Theme.App.SplashScreen in the manifest, the dialog is centered again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're experiencing this issue, here's a possible workaround. It includes nesting two Column composables and wrapping them in a Box. The Dialog UI is then applied within the nested Column.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ConfirmDialog(
    title: String,
    description: String,
    onCancelClicked: () -> Unit,
    onAcceptClicked: () -> Unit,
    @StringRes acceptText: Int = R.string.confirm,
) {
    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = onCancelClicked,
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clickable(
                    onClick = onCancelClicked,
                    indication = null,
                    interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
                )
        ) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
            ) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary, shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)
                        .padding(MaterialTheme.spacing.medium),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                ) {
                    Text(
                        text = title,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineSmall
                    )
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(MaterialTheme.spacing.medium))
                    Text(text = description, style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center)
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(MaterialTheme.spacing.medium))
                    DialogButtons(
                        onCancelClicked = onCancelClicked,
                        onAcceptClicked = onAcceptClicked,
                        acceptText = acceptText
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dialog button design is up to you but it is useful to separate if you use it in other composables too.

```kotlin
@Composable
private fun DialogButtons(
    @StringRes acceptText: Int,
    onCancelClicked: () -> Unit, onAcceptClicked: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(MaterialTheme.spacing.medium),
    ) {
        Button(
            textId = R.string.cancel,
            onButtonClick = onCancelClicked,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary),
            textColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
        )
        Button(
            textId = acceptText,
            onButtonClick = onAcceptClicked,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error),
            textColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
        )
    }
}
```